# In Black Ops, are any of the assault rifles fully automatic?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

So far, the rifle's I've come across are either burst fire or single fire.  Are any of the rifles fully automatic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a correct list of rifles that are automatic:

**Automatic Assult Rifles**

Enfield

Famas

Galil

AUG

AK-47

Commando

[Call of Duty Black Ops Weapon chart with damage, range, rate of fire, recoil, ammo, reload time, and body multipliers](http://www.joinaclan.com/2010/11/cod-black-ops-weapon-damage-chart/) to help you choose the right weapon for you =)

Hope this helps

Comment: I am pretty sure G11 is 3-shot-burst and not full-auto.

Comment: Your right, I don't know how that one slipped by me!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Automatic weapons in COD Black ops are:

- MP5k
- Skorpion
- MAC11
- AK-74u
- Uzi
- PM63
- MPL
- Spectre
- OTs-02 Kiparis
- M16
- Enfield
- M14
- FAMAS
- Galil
- FN FAL
- AK-47
- Commando
- G11
- HK21
- RPK-74
- M60
- Death Machine
- CZ75

Some weapons need to change the mode of fire, set to automatic.

Comment: The M14 is a single shot rifle. The M16 (in multiplayer) only shoots in three round bursts. The FN FAL is also semi-automatic. In short, your list is not correct.

Comment: Haven't used it in the game, but, since when is FN FAL full-auto weapon?

Comment: @Bora When I was in Los Vegas last there was a firing range where you could shoot an FN FAL.  The thing feels more like a nail driver than a rifle.  I asked the guy why it was single shot, and not full auto and he told me that the recoil is too harsh on full auto and that most military organizations don't train FAL use as full auto.  Wikipedia [backed him up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FN_FAL#Design_details), so I believe the man.

Comment: Thanks for the info, tzenes. Read that Wiki article just now.